# Pandas merging cells under a perticular column in to one

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

how can I merge all the cells under column for a value in another column?

eg : for the below DF data for each country value in 'Country' column value I want to merge the cells under the columns 'Age_group' and 'Age_group_percentage' into one cell.

[image]

the expected output should be like the below one,

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the difference between the two snippets?

Comment: @LazyCoder Sorry..Have updated.

Comment: is the columns order matter? I am thinking about - set age group as an index

Comment: @RanCohen Yes.we need to keep the column order also

Comment: so, I didn't find a way to do it with pd.data frame. it's more graphical or excels =\